# 'java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk' error when reading a .xlsx file in Java

Tags: java, ioexception

My initial assumption was that the drive that is the workspace of my project (F:) was full, but when I checked, I noticed that 425 GB of 497 FB was still unused. The excel file that I'm trying to read is in F:.

Any solutions for this issue?

Also, this is probably a silly question to most of y'all, but is 'disk' and 'drive' the same thing?

EDIT: so I did not attach my code because the error gets thrown right at the start of the code:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream ("F://Sample_for_FD_insert.xlsx"));
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
  {
   Row row1 = sheet.getRow(i);  
   for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
  {
  if(row1.getCell(j)==(null)) 
{  
break;
}
excel_headers.add(fmt.formatCellValue(row1.getCell(j)));
}
}
```

and My Excel file is a 9 KB file with a couple of columns
[image]

Comment: could you share the mentioned excel file?

Comment: and some code!!!

Comment: Show us ur code. I suspect you are reading or writing to somewhere else and not F drive ;-)

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace, since it'll give valuable information about where and why the error occurs.

Comment: I suspect that apache-poi is creating a temp file and by default the JVM temp folder is in C:/user/somethingIDontRememebr/Temp. So check if your c: drive has enough space or else start the JVM by overriding the temp folder env value: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace.  (I find it hard to believe that you will get a "not enough space on disk" error while **reading** something.  I would like to see the evidence of what is *actually* going on.)